# merge time dataframes with different Hz

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes with different frequencies without losing the data in one dataframe.

Example:

```
df1:

time   A
0.1    1
0.2    2
0.3    3
0.4    4
0.5    5
```

```
df2:

time   B
0.09   10
0.18   9
0.27   8
0.36   7
```

Goal is a merged df like:

```
time   A   B
0.09   NaN 10
0.10   1   NaN
0.18   NaN 9
0.20   2   NaN
0.27   NaN 8
0.30   3   NaN
0.36   NaN 7
0.4    4   NaN
0.5    5   NaN
```

I am new to python (and programming) and tried `merge` and `concat` but receive either errors, Empty Frames or "outer" Frames where the data´s just stick to the bottom with their own time repetition. Is there a way to combine the data like above or do I have to cut the decimals of the time parameters and accept the inaccuracy to the smallest amount?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(by='time')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` with `outer` option ( it's just like `OUTER JOIN` within `SQL` (*Structured Query Language*) of Databases ) as

```
print(pd.merge(df1,df2,on='time',how='outer',sort=True))
```

Comment: ah ok thank you, i missed sort=True in the documentation. That solves the problem!